# Is this topic valid? I think it is for Super User

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, migration

I know it has about 454 votes, but it is not related to programming, so I think it should migrate or get deleted. It's obviously off-topic.

Should we keep a post because it has so many upvotes even if it's off-topic?

### Why Off-topic?

One of the off-topic options when you want to flag a question is this:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Also when you use the question guide to ask a question you see this page:

> We’ll help you determine if Stack Overflow is the right place for your
>   question. If your question:
>
> - Includes a bit of source code
> - Concerns a specific coding issue, algorithm, or language
> - Isn’t opinion-based

>

> ...then continue asking your question.
>
> If your question doesn’t meet this criteria, don’t worry! We’ll help
>   you find a better place to post your question.

*[How do I determine if a port is open on a Windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273159/how-to-determine-if-a-port-is-open-on-a-windows-server)*

Comment: I think SuperUser wasn't around at that point. At any rate, I don't think it hurts anybody or hiners anything, so I'm not sure there is value in doing anything about it. It might be moved but then again moving every single historic question that was good but belongs to a different stack, seems like just wasted effort.

Comment: Is it off-topic? Determining if a port is open / available can be considered a programming task, specially nowadays with all these automatic deployment stuff in containers. It is on the devops end of the software engineering spectrum

Comment: @rene but the answers in the thread do not use code, just command-line commands. SuperUser was not around at that point so stack seems the best site to post that question. Users don't care on which site they are getting answers, they just want answers and then they upvote

Comment: @rene It is off-topic, As many other posts like this is considered as off-topic, Also all commands can be used somewhere in programming but it is not about code. It should be about code.

Comment: Posts older than 60 days can’t be migrated, even by moderators, so that’s not an option here.

Comment: @VLAZ I know but it's not so beautiful when we downvote new users post for being off-topic but we have such a topic with more than 400 votes...

Comment: @M4HdYaR No, answers do not necessarily need to be *about* code. They very often involve code, true, but that's just because most of the programming problems we face are *with* code. You can also have a question that is language agnostic like an algorithm or a programming concept. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337727/understanding-abstraction-in-oop) is a question with no code at all that is valid.

Comment: @rene so what is the point of creating different communities ?

Comment: @VLAZ I know But it is not about algorithm nor a programming concept.

Comment: @weegee those are certainly tools I have used in my capacity as developer and content about tools used by developers is on-topic.

Comment: @M4HdYaR for example, check out the [power-shell] tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell its mostly not about code but command-line interfaces but still on-topic.

Comment: @weegee It is , According to SO : 
Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @weegee It can be done for many intents, penetration testing, Connecting with a software, Configure your modem, Port forwarding .....

Comment: Asking a question to detect open ports with any _varieties_ of ways is considered a question regarding tools, used _**primarily**_ for programming.  Notice the words here. Penetration testing, Port forwarding are some things that can use this thread which is Good! But the truth is, it is mostly used for programming. @M4HdYaR

Comment: @M4HdYaR "*so what is the point of creating different communities ?*" I'd like for you to remember what the purpose of the whole of SE is - to be a repository of valuable content to other users. This is valuable content to other users. Why do you want it *gone*?

Comment: @VLAZ Because we delete or migrate every other new off-topic posts regardless of it is helpful or not.

Comment: @weegee Why do you think open ports use primarily for programming ?!!! Many SysAdmins use it without knowing anything about programming...

Comment: In theory CMs can migrate posts even after 60 days, but they do it only very rarely.

Answer (score 8):

You are wasting your time asking for this question to be migrated.

The questions is more than 60 days old (by a long way) and cannot be migrated.

Whether it's on topic for Stack Overflow is irrelevant at this point.

If you think it's off topic then just flag or vote to close and move on.

It's not uncommon for off-topic questions to remain open until someone questions it here. In the first instance not everyone will agree that it's off topic. Secondly it might not be seen by enough 3,000+ rep users before any existing close votes age away, etc.

Comment: I'm already flagged and it is now on hold, My question was why this post isn't known as off-topic till now. Also note it had an update 8 month ago.

Comment: @M4HdYaR the post received a close vote (from a well-respected community member with a very good track record of community moderation) but the close review never gained enough attention so the close vote aged away.

Comment: The post was voted as belonging on Server Fault in January 2012 but didn’t gain enough close votes and another “professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration” CV failed in 2015, again due to lack of attention, not because people disagreed.

Answer (score -1):

> it is not related to programming

I beg to differ. Knowing which port is open is also a task developers often face.

> so I think it should migrate

As it is older than 60 days, that isn't an option.

> or get deleted

That would need 5 close votes first and then around 10 delete votes. That is 15 users that need to get involved ... for one question ...

> It's obviously off-topic.

The concept of open/closed ports is relevant for a developer and you need tools to query those ports. That makes that both the task and the tools are a frequent activity for software developers and that makes such questions on-topic.

And from a comment

> As many other posts like this is considered as off-topic, Also all commands can be used somewhere in programming but it is not about code. It should be about code.

It is likely that there are some (many) posts that are considered off-topic which you can compare with this one but that is not what you asked. And no, questions on SO doesn't need to be solely about code or involve code. Questions about tools used by developers is such an example and so are algorithm or well scoped how-to questions. Those don't have code either and are on-topic.

In response to various comments it is worth mentioning that the fact that to solve a task with a tool can be used in a non-developer setting as well or that questions about a tool are on-topic elsewhere *does not* make that topic off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Are we sure there aren't less popular and, more important, newer questions that needs moderation? That post doesn't hurt the site in any way, it is protected to prevent non-answers from new users. It is fine as it is.

Comment: According to SO : Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @M4HdYaR from  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic *software tools commonly used by programmers*

Comment: @M4HdYaR I disagree that Windows Server is for "general computing"

Comment: Looks like you are confusing the word _general_. _General computing_ here means question like _How do I open the start menu on windows_? Which are _general_  @M4HdYaR

Comment: @VLAZ It is as many non programmers use windows server.

Comment: @M4HdYaR the fact that it's Windows Server would tend to preclude it from being on topic for Super User.

Comment: @M4HdYaR that doesn't make it a general tool. It's still specialised - people aren't running Windows Server at their desktops at home. Not on a massive scale, at least.

Comment: @VLAZ I agree it is specialized but not specialized to programmers.

Comment: Oh, come on. Windows Server, Windows 10, Linux, etc. the operative system doesn't matter. General OS questions aren't programming questions.

Comment: @Braiam but it was a nice exercise in trying to win an argument  ....

Comment: It’s a bit borderline. The point where developer use of general computing knowledge turns into full on *general computing* is a blurry one. I’m inclined to see this one on the wrong side of the line but don’t feel strongly enough about it to mod-hammer it at this point.

Comment: But the argument that a developer often needs to check if a port is open is a *very slippery slope*, ending in asking how to best keep your laptop connected to the internet while working on a boat... Just because a developer and a computer is involved doesn’t protect a question from being off topic for *general computing* reasons. The specific OS notwithstanding.

Comment: (The *Windows Server* argument makes it sound like a topic for Server Fault; a different  specialised subset of computing topics).